# Group Policy Error Code 0x80070005

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, group-policy

We have a group policy set up, it's a computer policy that moves a file from a network location to the standard Windows wallpaper location C:\Windows\Web\wallpaper. A user policy then sets the desktop background to that file. It works for all but 1 computer, which is getting a black background because the file never copies. When a report is run looking at that policy, it fails giving the error code '0x80070005'.

I've done some research, finding out it's an access denied error, but most of the answers relate to the computer or the user not having access to the file, both the computer and the user do. Also the policy is applied to a group of computers, every other computer is not having an issue copying that file, just this one.

I've done a reporting wizard, and the rest of the computers are still copying the file over with no issues, it really is just this one computer. I've checked, and it's in the same group (just a generic 'Domain Computers' group), and the user has all the permissions he should, he can go into that file and open it if he wants.

Does anyone know what might be causing the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you verified the user has permission to copy the file.

Comment: Under the Common tab in GPP, Is the “Run in Logged on User’s Security Context” checked? You can refer to the topic "Security Context in Group Policy Preferences" in the following link: http://deployhappiness.com/run-in-logged-on-users-security-context/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. The user does have permissions to copy the file, yes; they don't have permission to put it in wallpaper folder, but it's the Computer that has permission to do this, not the user Also the "Run in Logged on User's Security Context" is greyed out, as it's a Computer level policy, rather than a User one.

Answer (score 1):

What I found was a simple issue in the GPO file dialogue box, I was putting the destination path with out specifying the destination file name and extension also. Once I filled that out correctly all errors went away and files came down.